# Automate Listbox Selection

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox, multi-select

I have a listbox that I want to be able to automate so that when I enter the total quantity of an item it will multi-select the rows until it reaches that total. Is what I want to do possible within the confines of MS Access?  I have been searching and searching and can't seem to find anything to show me where to start.

```
' Spin through the Array adding up rows to fulfill the needed quantity, following will search and possibly use part of a BIN
    If ListArray(i, 1) <> "" And ListArray(i, 1) <= iQty Then           ' skip empty array; check if less than qty
        While index <= Me.lstShipping.ListCount
            lstShipping(ListArray(i, 0)) = True                         ' select this row in ListBox
            iSelected = iSelected + ListArray(i, 1)                     ' track total qty selected
                If iSelected = iQty Then                                ' if enough is selected, end
                    Exit While
                End If
        index += 1
        End While
```

Comment: I don't understand. What is in the listbox to start? Where is the total entered? What does the listbox look like afterward?

Comment: The listbox contains list of Storage Containers (BINS) in a Warehouse. Each of these BINS contain a number of a certain product, and each product has a lot number. I have a query to pull that and populate it to a listbox on a form.

There can be numerous BINS containing the same lot number, so what I am wanting to do is when I ship a certain lot number it grabs a total that I enter from the main form and selects the corresponding lots until it has enough to equal the total.

I can filter the listbox, but not how I want to filter it. Does that clear things up?

Comment: Yes, I'm fairly certain in VBA you can do this. For clarity, lets say your listbox has 5 items with the following values 1,2,3,4,5.  If you enter  a total of 6, you want the first 3 items selected. But what happens if you enter 7? Do you want to select items 3 & 4?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn... Ideally, I would want to use 1, 2, & 4 so I could empty the most BINS possible and free them for other shipments; but I am not picky at this point and can tweak it later after a workable solution is setup.

Comment: I modified the code so that it starts with the smallest qty's first. Depending on # of bins, qty's in bins, qty desired, you MAY get a message because it is too complicated. Give it a try and see if this new code is close to what you need....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to add missing Function... The following code will spin through your listbox looking for matching 'Lot #'s' and selecting rows that will provide the desired quantity. The listbox qty's are placed into an array, then sorted so it will take smallest qty's first to free up most bins. I was too lazy to have code deselect more than one previously selected row to arrive at correct qty, but a msgbox will alert you to that. Just call the function passing the quantity and Lot# .

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim myarray()       As Variant

Private Sub cmdSearchBins_Click()
    Mark_ListBox_Rows Me.txtQty, "Lot-A"
End Sub

Function Mark_ListBox_Rows(Qty As Integer, LotNbr As String)
Dim i       As Integer
Dim i2      As Integer
Dim iStart  As Integer
Dim iQty    As Integer
Dim iReserved   As Integer
Dim iAddRow     As Integer
Dim iColUsed    As Integer
Dim iMaxQtyAvail    As Integer

'(1)Either pass the qty (and Lot #) to this routine, or change code to get Qty from another control and set iQty
'(2) Modify code for correct column (I am using col 4 (3 if relative to zero))
'(3) Most times automatic selection will be made. If unable to find simple (one row) solution, let the user pick.

iColUsed = 3        ' (relative to zero)
iMaxQtyAvail = 0

If IsNull(Qty) Or Qty = 0 Then
    MsgBox "You must specify the Quantity!", vbOKOnly, "No Quantity Entered"
    Exit Function
End If


If Me.List2.ColumnHeads = True Then         ' Check if listbox has headings
    iStart = 1                              ' Adjust starting row + 1
Else
    iStart = 0
End If

ReDim myarray(Me.List2.ListCount, 2)        'Resize Array as needed

'Populate Array with ListBox Row & Qty
i2 = 0
For i = 0 To Me.List2.ListCount             ' Spin through listbox
    If Me.List2.Column(2, iStart + i) = LotNbr Then             ' Make sure Lot # matches
        If Me.List2.Column(iColUsed, iStart + i) <> 0 Then      ' Make sure not = 0 (doubt it is in your list, but...)
            myarray(i2, 0) = iStart + i2                        ' Save Row number, then Qty
            myarray(i2, 1) = Int(Me.List2.Column(iColUsed, iStart + i))
            iMaxQtyAvail = iMaxQtyAvail + Int(Me.List2.Column(iColUsed, iStart + i))
            'Debug.Print "List Row: " & i2 & vbTab & "Qty: " & myarray(i2, 1)
            i2 = i2 + 1
        End If
    End If
Next i

If iMaxQtyAvail < Qty Then
    MsgBox "All rows combined only have a quantity of: " & iMaxQtyAvail & vbCrLf & "You asked for quantity of : " & Qty, vbOKOnly, "Insufficient Quantity Available"
    GoTo End_Here
End If

myarray = BubbleSrt(myarray, True)                          ' Sort my Array by Quantity

'    For i = 0 To UBound(myarray)                                ' List what the Array looks like after sorting.
'        Debug.Print "Array: " & i & vbTab & myarray(i, 0) & " - " & myarray(i, 1)
'    Next i

iQty = Qty
iReserved = 0

For i = 0 To Me.List2.ListCount             'Deselect ALL rows in Listbox - in case someone already started....
    List2.Selected(i) = False
Next i

For i = 0 To UBound(myarray)                ' Spin through the Array adding up rows to fulfill the desired quantity
    'The following will search and possibly use part of a bin.
    If myarray(i, 1) <> "" And myarray(i, 1) <= iQty Then           ' Skip empty Array; check if <= Qty
        If iReserved + myarray(i, 1) <= iQty Then
            'Debug.Print "Row: " & myarray(iStart + i, 0) & vbTab & "Qty: " & myarray(iStart + i, 1)
            List2.Selected(myarray(i, 0)) = True       ' Select this row in Listbox
            iReserved = iReserved + myarray(i, 1)       ' Keep track of total reserved so far
            If iReserved = iQty Then                            ' If just the right number, get outta here!
                'Me.txtReserved = iReserved
                GoTo End_Here
            End If
        Else    ' Need to Adjust
            ' Not so simple. Need to see if can deselect a prior selected row and keep this row to arrive at total.
            'Debug.Print "Need to Adjust; Qty Required / Current Reserved + ListItem = " & Qty & " / " & iReserved + myarray(iStart + i, 1)
            iAddRow = i                                 ' Save the row with the qty that would put us over the limit.
            For i2 = iStart + i To 1 Step -1            ' Walk backwards so we deselect largest qty.
                If ((iReserved + myarray(iAddRow, 1)) - myarray(i2, 1)) = iQty Then
                    ' Found the right combination. Deselect this row, and select the row from earlier
                    'Debug.Print "Swap Rows"
                    List2.Selected(myarray(i2, 0)) = False          ' Unselect this row in Listbox
                    List2.Selected(myarray(iAddRow, 0)) = True      ' Select this row in Listbox
                    iReserved = iReserved + myarray(iAddRow, 1) - myarray(i2, 1)   ' Count Total Reserved
                    'Me.txtReserved = iReserved
                    GoTo End_Here
                End If
            Next i2
            ' Yikes! I don't frrl like coding to handle deselecting some combination of 2 or more!!!
            MsgBox "Qty Needed = " & Qty & vbCrLf & "Qty selected = " & iReserved & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please manually select/deselect to obtain desired quantity", vbOKOnly, "Manually Select Quantity"
            GoTo End_Here
        End If
    End If
Next i

    If iQty > iReserved Then
        MsgBox "Unable to find sufficient part quantity!", vbOKOnly, "Not Enough Parts"
        'Deselect ALL
        For i = 0 To Me.List2.ListCount
            List2.Selected(i) = False
        Next i
    End If

End_Here:
'Me.txtQty = Me.txtQty + 1
End Function

Public Function BubbleSrt(ArrayIn As Variant, Ascending As Boolean)

Dim SrtTemp As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim SrtTemp0 As Variant
Dim SrtTemp1 As Variant

If Ascending = True Then
    For i = LBound(ArrayIn) To UBound(ArrayIn)
         For j = i + 1 To UBound(ArrayIn)
             If ArrayIn(i, 1) > ArrayIn(j, 1) Then
                 SrtTemp0 = ArrayIn(j, 0)
                 SrtTemp1 = ArrayIn(j, 1)
                 ArrayIn(j, 0) = ArrayIn(i, 0)
                 ArrayIn(j, 1) = ArrayIn(i, 1)
                 ArrayIn(i, 0) = SrtTemp0
                 ArrayIn(i, 1) = SrtTemp1
             End If
         Next j
     Next i
Else
    For i = LBound(ArrayIn) To UBound(ArrayIn)
         For j = i + 1 To UBound(ArrayIn)
             If ArrayIn(i) < ArrayIn(j) Then
                 SrtTemp = ArrayIn(j)
                 ArrayIn(j) = ArrayIn(i)
                 ArrayIn(i) = SrtTemp
             End If
         Next j
     Next i
End If

BubbleSrt = ArrayIn

End Function
```

Comment: Two questions: (1) I'm fairly certain the listbox is sorted by either Bin # or Lot# or both? (2) How many columns in the listbox (I assume at least 3: |Bin|Lot|Qty|), and what order are the columns?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out this evening...
1. Sorted by BIN#, but I can sort by whatever is best.
2. | BIN# | SKU | Lot# | Product Qty | Pallet Qty |

Comment: Does your listbox have headings? I can handele if it does.

Comment: I am getting an error at the BubbleSrt(myarray, True)... is there a function I need to add to get this to work because I am not aware of a built in BubbleSort function.

Comment: My bad - I just updated the answer to include the other Function (at the end) -- Sorry!

Comment: Thanks... I am going to have to tweak it a bit but that is definitely what I was wanting to do. I have a lot more to learn before I am as good as I want to be in programming Access and VBA.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn... would a While Loop work to select each row until the Qty is meet, since using the BubbleSort first?  I have it coded but just don't think I have it setup correctly... added code to the original post.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use a 'While' of 'For' or 'Do' - as long as the logic inside the loop produces the correct result - marking the correct rows to provide an exact match on the quantity. As I mentioned in the 'Answer', I didn't spend extra effort dealing with cases where you need to 'unselect' more than one item to meet the quantity. For example: Bin Qty=1,1,1,3,4; you're looking for 8. After you select 1,1,1,3 then 4 will put you over by 2. Per my example, your 'While' may never hit exact qty.